# "Who does this course fit for" Vs. "To whom does this course fit for"?

Tags: difference, idiomatic-language, who-whom

What is the difference between

> "**Who** does this course fit for"

and

> "**To whom** does this course fit for"?

And are they build correctly? My purpose is to ask to which people this course fits (but I'm not sure if the word "fit" is correct in that context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use either of these. They are awkward. Your use of "does ... fit for" is the main problem here.

Try  "Who is this course for?" or "Who is this course intended for?".

Forget trying to use *whom* in these questions, it's too formal for speech, and almost on the verge of being considered archaic. If you must use *whom*, then in very formal English you could write: "For whom is this course intended?", but it has an almost archaic feel to it, and some may perceive it as pedantic if you were to speak like that.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ^+1. I would like to ask and note some things if don't mind. 1. Indeed it is for formal writing. Can I write: "Whom is this course intended **for**? and how about using the verb "aim" instead of "intended" in this context? (For whom is this course **aimed**?

Comment: No, put the "For" at the beginning. In very formal English such as this, it's best to avoid propositions at the end of a sentence. I don't think the verb aimed works well at all, use "intended".